# No visible @interface for 'PF Object'

Tags: ios, string, label, parse-platform

I'm using Parse to retrieve an integer. Trying to convert the integer to a label I wrote:

`testLabel.text = [score stringValue];`

"score" is the variable I am trying to get the value of. When I run this, I get the error: No visible @interface for 'PF Object' declares the selector "stringValue."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests, the score is an instance of PFObject. You can only send *stringValue* message to NSNumber instance.

You need to get the value out of PFObject first. For example, if the key is called scoreNumber:

```
NSString *scoreString = [[score objectForKey:@"scoreNumber"] stringValue];
```

Check the [parse docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects/iOS) for more information.